# How to specify VARCHAR column length in custom data persister?

Tags: ormlite

I have a custom persister which stores ZonedDateTimes as strings in my database. OrmLite is generating column definition `VARCHAR(0)` which is invalid in PostgreSQL.

I need to specify a length but I am not sure the best way to do it.

I know I could do something like

```
    @DatabaseField(columnName = "my_column",
                   persisterClass = MyCustomPersister.class,
                   columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(17)")
```

But I would have to do this for every declaration of a field with this datatype. That means that every field annotated with DatabaseField(persisterClass=MyCustomPersister.class) should always be in SQL a VARCHAR of length 17

Is there a way to fix this problem in the data persister?

Comment: This is unclear _"I would have to do this for every declaration of a field with this datatype"_ if you want to specify a length, how do you expect to do it otherwise?  It would be rather pointless to declare "All varchars are to have a length of 17".  You need to declare the explicit length on each varchar column.

Comment: @JimGarrison I meant that every field annotated with `DatabaseField(persisterClass=MyCustomPersister.class)` should always be a VARCHAR of length 17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is enough with just overriding the method `int getDefaultWidth();` in the data persister